# Unit-check for pressure

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, dimensional-analysis, si-units

according to the barometric formula $p(h) = p_0\cdot e^{-\dfrac{g\cdot h}{R_s\cdot T}}$

That means the expression $\dfrac{g\cdot h}{R_s\cdot T}$ has to be out of units. I can't approve that: $$[\frac{g\cdot h}{R_s\cdot T}] = \dfrac{\frac{m}{s^2}\cdot m}{\frac{Nm}{\text{mol}\cdot K}\cdot K} = \dfrac{\frac{m^2}{s^2}}{\frac{Kg}{\text{mol}}\cdot\frac{m^2}{s^2}} = \dfrac{\text{mol}}{Kg}$$

So what?

Comment: It seems to me that you've done your units correctly. However I found in other places that the exponent is given by: $\frac{-Mgh}{RT}$ (you're missing a negative, unless you're taking height to be oriented towards the center of the earth). Since this is the case, and $M$ has units of $\frac{kg}{mol}$, then this resolves your question. Perhaps the question implicitly assumes that you're using a gas with this molar mass? Or perhaps the equation is written incorrectly?

Comment: Well, it seems that $R_s \equiv R/M$ denotes the [specific gas constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_constant#Specific_gas_constant)?!

Comment: Leon, you are missing a "M" term in the numerator.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometric_formula

Comment: Yea, I'm alway missing a minus sign. Also I was referring to $R_s$, the specific gas constant but  ... well, I took the units of the ordinary gas constant. That resolves it all